# JavaScript Engine in Universal Windows App (C#,XAML)

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-8, win-universal-app

I am developing an Universal Windows App using c# and XAML. And the requirement is in the App I need to pass a value to a Javascript code to get a result.

Is there any JavaScript engine for Universal Windows App similar to JavaScriptCore in IOS. If so please advice me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Jint (https://github.com/sebastienros/jint). I just tested and confirmed that it works in XAML Universal Apps. Just add the NuGet package and follow the docs.

From the official docs:

```cs
    var engine = new Engine()
        .SetValue("log", new Action<object>(Console.WriteLine));

    engine.Execute(@"
      function hello() { 
        log('Hello World');
      };

      hello();
    ");
```

Comment: Thanks a Bunch @alexchardin

Answer (score 1):

You can host Microsoft's JavaScript Runtime (JsRT) in Universal Windows Platform apps. This will allow your app to process scripts with the Edge Chakra engine.

See [Hosting the JavaScript Runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249552(v=vs.94).aspx#Windows) on MSDN for details.

Comment: will it support in Windows 8.1? Since its processing scripts with Edge Chakra engine